# Callback while subclass constructor completed

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, constructor

I would like to know if there is a mechanism or built-in function for super-class to do something once the sub-class complete its constructor function?

Or I need to build it myself ?

Something like:

```
Class Parent {
  constructor(){
    console.log(1);
  }

  constructorComplete(){
    console.log(5);
  }
}


Class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(){
    super()
    console.log(2);
  }

  constructorComplete(){
    console.log(4);
    // super.constructorComplete();
  }
}


Class Grandchild extends Child {
  constructor(){
    super()
    console.log(3);
    // super.constructorComplete();
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: A superclass should know nothing about its descendants. Sounds like you have a leaky abstraction...

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - are you able to describe why you want to do this, there may be a more suitable pattern to use.

Comment: A constructor should never "*do*" something, it should only initialise the instance and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks all, I would like to add every the instance into a list.  So I added `list.push(this)` in the superclass's constructor.  But I want the instance has been well initialized before adding to the list, and there are multiple subclass.  I don't want to put `list.push(this)` in those subclass.  Anyway, if a constructor should never "do" something, should I just use `list.push(new SubClass())` ?

Comment: @SamuelWong Yes, doing the `list.push()` outside of the instantiation is much, much cleaner. It also doesn't limit the class(es) to a single global list.

Comment: @SamuelWong "*I want the instance has been well initialized before adding to the list*" - that shouldn't actually matter, unless the `list.push` is not the array method but something that inspects the instance.

Comment: Thanks! Can you answer it and I will choose it as the best answer.

Comment: Actually, it is matter.  You are correct if it is just a normal array.  However, it is a `MobX observable array`.  It will trigger the render of a `React component`.  When the instance is not yet well initialized, its property is undefined and can not be displayed on the `React component`.